# Heroku Scheduled Task that uses Net::HTTP library to make HTTP GET request - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, http-get, net-http

I'm trying to use a Heroku Scheduled Task that makes an HTTP GET to a particular controller's action. Here's what the task looks like:

```
require 'net/http'

desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :send_notifications => :environment do
    Net::HTTP.get("http://testapp.com", "/test/send_notifications")
end
```

Upon running:

```
heroku rake send_notifications
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
/app/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To run rake on Heroku I think you should actually call `heroku run rake db:migrate` etc. from your command line.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution might be to put the request logic inside a class method of a special Class you create anywhere in your Rails app directory.

```
# app/workers/request_worker.rb
class RequestWorker
  # Request X from Y
  def self.retrieve_testapp
    # Do anything nescessary to build and execute the request in here
  end
end
```

You could then schedule the request with the Heroku Scheduler addon by way of Rails runner (which let's you execute any command in the context of your Rails application.)

```
rails runner RequestWorker.retrieve_testapp
```

To actually execute an HTTP Request from Ruby / Rails there are [a lot of useful gems](http://www.knight.io/categories/http-clients-ruby). Nice ones are [Excon](https://github.com/geemus/excon) and [HTTP Client](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the 'HTTParty' library which has taken care of it:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://testapp.com/test/send_notifications')
```